# How to pass a Rust function as a callback to Python using pyo3

Tags: python, rust, callback, pyo3

I am using Pyo3 to call Rust functions from Python and vice versa.

I am trying to achieve the following:

- Python calls `rust_function_1`
- Rust function `rust_function_1` calls Python function `python_function` passing Rust function `rust_function_2` as a callback argument
- Python function `python_function` calls the callback, which in this case is Rust function `rust_function_2`

I cannot figure out how to pass `rust_function_2` as a callback argument to `python_function`.

I have the following Python code:

```py
import rust_module

def python_function(callback):
    print("This is python_function")
    callback()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rust_module.rust_function_1()
```

And I have the following non-compiling Rust code:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyfunction]
fn rust_function_1() -> PyResult<()> {
    println!("This is rust_function_1");
    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let python_module = PyModule::import(py, "python_module")?;
        python_module
            .getattr("python_function")?
            .call1((rust_function_2.into_py(py),))?;  // Compile error
        Ok(())
    })
}

#[pyfunction]
fn rust_function_2() -> PyResult<()> {
    println!("This is rust_function_2");
    Ok(())
}

#[pymodule]
#[pyo3(name = "rust_module")]
fn quantum_network_stack(_python: Python, module: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    module.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rust_function_1, module)?)?;
    module.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rust_function_2, module)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

The error message is:

```
error[E0599]: the method `into_py` exists for fn item `fn() -> Result<(), PyErr> {rust_function_2}`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:10:37
   |
10 |             .call1((rust_function_2.into_py(py),))?;
   |                                     ^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `fn() -> Result<(), PyErr> {rust_function_2}` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: `rust_function_2` is a function, perhaps you wish to call it
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `fn() -> Result<(), PyErr> {rust_function_2}: AsPyPointer`
           which is required by `&fn() -> Result<(), PyErr> {rust_function_2}: pyo3::IntoPy<Py<PyAny>>`
```

Comment: The [pyo3 docs](https://pyo3.rs/latest/function.html#calling-rust-functions-in-python) say the following: "For dynamic functions, e.g. lambdas and functions that were passed as arguments, you must put them in some kind of owned container, e.g. a `Box`. ... You can then use a `#[pyclass]` struct with that container as a field as a way to pass the function over the FFI barrier. You can even make that class callable with `__call__` so it looks like a function in Python code."

Comment: @PitaJ Thank you very much. This solved the problem. Answer based on this suggestion posted below. (If you would like credit for the answer, please post the same answer and I will accept it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment from PitaJ led me to the solution.

Rust code that works:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
struct Callback {
    #[allow(dead_code)] // callback_function is called from Python
    callback_function: fn() -> PyResult<()>,
}

#[pymethods]
impl Callback {
    fn __call__(&self) -> PyResult<()> {
        (self.callback_function)()
    }
}

#[pyfunction]
fn rust_function_1() -> PyResult<()> {
    println!("This is rust_function_1");
    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let python_module = PyModule::import(py, "python_module")?;
        let callback = Box::new(Callback {
            callback_function: rust_function_2,
        });
        python_module
            .getattr("python_function")?
            .call1((callback.into_py(py),))?;
        Ok(())
    })
}

#[pyfunction]
fn rust_function_2() -> PyResult<()> {
    println!("This is rust_function_2");
    Ok(())
}

#[pymodule]
#[pyo3(name = "rust_module")]
fn quantum_network_stack(_python: Python, module: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    module.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rust_function_1, module)?)?;
    module.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rust_function_2, module)?)?;
    module.add_class::<Callback>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Python code that works (same as in the question):

```py
import rust_module

def python_function(callback):
    print("This is python_function")
    callback()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rust_module.rust_function_1()
```

The following solution improves on the above solition in a number of ways:

- The `callback` provided by Rust is stored and called later, instead of being called immediately (this is more realistic for real-life use cases)
- Each time when Python calls Rust, it passes in a `PythonApi` object removes the need for Rust function to do a Python `import` every time they are called.
- The callback provided by Rust can be closures that capture variables (move semantics only) in addition to plain functions.

The more general Rust code is as follows:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
struct Callback {
    #[allow(dead_code)] // callback_function is called from Python
    callback_function: Box<dyn Fn(&PyAny) -> PyResult<()> + Send>,
}

#[pymethods]
impl Callback {
    fn __call__(&self, python_api: &PyAny) -> PyResult<()> {
        (self.callback_function)(python_api)
    }
}

#[pyfunction]
fn rust_register_callback(python_api: &PyAny) -> PyResult<()> {
    println!("This is rust_register_callback");
    let message: String = "a captured variable".to_string();
    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let callback = Box::new(Callback {
            callback_function: Box::new(move |python_api| {
                rust_callback(python_api, message.clone())
            }),
        });
        python_api
            .getattr("set_callback")?
            .call1((callback.into_py(py),))?;
        Ok(())
    })
}

#[pyfunction]
fn rust_callback(python_api: &PyAny, message: String) -> PyResult<()> {
    println!("This is rust_callback");
    println!("Message = {}", message);
    python_api.getattr("some_operation")?.call0()?;
    Ok(())
}

#[pymodule]
#[pyo3(name = "rust_module")]
fn quantum_network_stack(_python: Python, module: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    module.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rust_register_callback, module)?)?;
    module.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rust_callback, module)?)?;
    module.add_class::<Callback>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

The more general Python code is as follows:

```py
import rust_module


class PythonApi:

    def __init__(self):
        self.callback = None

    def set_callback(self, callback):
        print("This is PythonApi::set_callback")
        self.callback = callback

    def call_callback(self):
        print("This is PythonApi::call_callback")
        assert self.callback is not None
        self.callback(self)

    def some_operation(self):
        print("This is PythonApi::some_operation")

def python_function(python_api, callback):
    print("This is python_function")
    python_api.callback = callback


def main():
    print("This is main")
    python_api = PythonApi()
    print("Calling rust_register_callback")
    rust_module.rust_register_callback(python_api)
    print("Returned from rust_register_callback; back in main")
    print("Calling callback")
    python_api.call_callback()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output from the latter version of code is as follows:

```
This is main
Calling rust_register_callback
This is rust_register_callback
This is PythonApi::set_callback
Returned from rust_register_callback; back in main
Calling callback
This is PythonApi::call_callback
This is rust_callback
Message = a captured variable
This is PythonApi::some_operation
```

Comment: You should probably "accept" your own answer, if that's not disallowed by Stackoverflow.